# Use setBackgroundColor() inside OnDragListener

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am new to Android.

Suppose I have 2 views: `myImage` and `myContainer`.

What I want to do: When I drag `myImage` and drop it into `myContainer`, `myContainer`'s background color will be changed.

In order to achieve this goal, I have tried 2 approaches:

1) Putting `setBackgroundColor()` inside `ACTION_DROP` like this:

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            ...
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                ...
                myContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

With this approach, when I dragged `myImage` and drop it into `myContainer`, the background color of `myContainer` changed to green, but only briefly, after that it automatically changed back to the old color.

2) Putting `setBackgroundColor()` inside `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` like this:

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            ...
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                ...
                myContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

With this approach, when I dragged `myImage` and drop it into `myContainer`, the background color of `myContainer` changed to green, but after that, if I started a new drag-and-drop action, it would automatically change back to the old color.

I find this behaviour of `setBackgroundColor()` quite hard to understand, because previously I always thought that it's effect is permanent.

Could you please explain to me why the color kept being reset in these situations, and how to make the color's change permanent.

Thanks.

Comment: are you setting the BackGround Color of your container somewhere else also??

Comment: @Anmol Hi anmol, I only set background color of the container in those lines of code (the ones I posted above), not anywhere else.